# How can I remove column in Propel ORM ver. 1.3?

Tags: symfony1, propel

I'm using Symfony with Propel ORM v.1.3. I need to change table schema in task, remove few columns exactly. How can I do that? I saw method addColumn in TableMap class, but there was no removeColumn or deleteColumn method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove a column you have to change the `schema.xml` and then [migrate your database](http://propelorm.org/Propel/documentation/10-migrations.html).

IMHO the Propel ORM isn't designed to add or remove columns programmatically. The `addColumn` function in the `TableMap` class isn't either. So it would be best if your task would somehow automate the steps described in the above mentioned documentation for migrations.